# How to extend returned objects in the list returned by $asArray?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm having trouble decorate the objects in my list returned by $asArray in angularfire with a new method (not decorating the array itself).

The angularfire documentation seems to suggest that the right way to do this is to override the $$added method in the factory for $FirebaseArray, returning a new object that either encapsulates or extends the snapshot that gets passed in to that method.  From the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-factories-firebasearray-extendfactory):

```
// an object to return in our JokeFactory
app.factory("Joke", function($firebaseUtils) {
  function Joke(snapshot) {
    this.$id = snapshot.name();
    this.update(snapshot);
  }

  Joke.prototype = {
    update: function(snapshot) {
      // apply changes to this.data instead of directly on `this`
      this.data = snapshot.val();
    },

    makeJoke: function() {
      alert("Why did the " + this.animal + " cross the " + this.obstacle + "?");
    },

    toJSON: function() {
      // since we didn't store our data directly on `this`, we need to return
      // it in parsed format. We can use the util function to remove $ variables
      // and get it ready to ship
      return $firebaseUtils.toJSON(this.data);
    }
  };

  return Joke;
});

app.factory("JokeFactory", function($FirebaseArray, Joke) {
  return $FirebaseArray.$extendFactory({
    // change the added behavior to return Joke objects
    $$added: function(snap) {
      return new Joke(snap);
    },

    // override the update behavior to call Joke.update()
    $$updated: function(snap) {
       this.$getRecord(snap.name()).update(snap);
    }
  });
});
```

However, when I do this in my code, nothing ever gets added to the array, although I can see from outputting to the console that it is getting called.

```
var printMessageObjConstructor = function(snap) {
      this.$id = snap.name();
      this.snapshot = snap;
      this.$update = function(snap) {
        this.snapshot = snap;
      };
      this.printMessage = function() {
        return this.author + "'s question is: " + this.body;
      };
    };

    var ref = new Firebase("https://danculley-test.firebaseio.com/questions");
    //What Am I Doing Wrong Here?
    var arrayFactory = $FirebaseArray.$extendFactory({
      $$added: function(snap, prevChild) {
        var x = new printMessageObjConstructor(snap);
        console.log("I am being called from FirebaseDecoratedCtlOverloadAddedinNewObj.");
        return x;
      },
      $createObject: function(snap) {
        return new printMessageObjConstructor(snap);
      },
      $$updated: function(snap) {
        var i = this.$indexFor(snap.name());
        var q = this.$list[i];
        q.$update(snap);
      }
    });
    var sync = $firebase(ref, {arrayFactory:arrayFactory});

    var list = sync.$asArray();

    list.$loaded(function(list) {
      $scope.questions = list;
    });
```

I've set up a new [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BkofLAtOfmH4FpTMQtDl) stripped down to show the issue with a couple other use cases that I've tried.  (The actual method I'm adding is more complex and isn't related to the view, but I wanted to do something simple to reproduce the issue.)

I think the issue is that I don't quite understand what exactly $$added is supposed to return, or what additional behavior beside returning the value to be stored $$added is supposed to have.  There also doesn't really seem to be an $$added on the prototype or on $FirebaseArray to call as a super to get the default behavior.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

For the benefit of others, after reviewing the like that Kato posted, I was able to solve the issue by adding the following, almost all copied directly from the source except for the commented line below.

```
$$added: function(snap, prevChild) {

        var i = this.$indexFor(snap.name());
          if( i === -1 ) {

            var rec = snap.val();
            if( !angular.isObject(rec) ) {
              rec = { $value: rec };
            }
            rec.$id = snap.name();
            rec.$priority = snap.getPriority();
            $firebaseUtils.applyDefaults(rec, this.$$defaults);

            //This is the line that I added to what I copied from the source
            angular.extend(rec, printMessageObj);


            this._process('child_added', rec, prevChild);
          }
      }
```

Comment: If you look at [the source for $$added](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseArray.js#L257), you'll see that it doesn't return anything. It applies the updates internally.

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer, @Kato.  As I've updated the post above, I was able to solve the issue by mostly copying and pasting from the source and adding one line.  I'm a little confused, though, why calling `$FirebaseArray.$$added.call(this, snap, prevChild);` from  the function doesn't work (it says that $$added doesn't exist on $FirebaseArray).  This also seems to contradict what's being done in the documentation.

Comment: I think the internal unwrapping makes this somewhat hard to extend; it would make more sense (to me at least), for this function to call another function before rec is processed with rec as an argument, then pass that to _process unless that function returns false.  In $FirebaseArray, that could be a no-op function, but that would be easy to extend to decorate the actual record.

Comment: Please add your solution as an actual answer and accept it. On StackOverflow it is acceptable to self-answer your own questions like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of others, after reviewing the link that Kato posted, I was able to solve the issue by adding the following, almost all copied directly from the source except for the commented line below.

```
$$added: function(snap, prevChild) {

    var i = this.$indexFor(snap.name());
      if( i === -1 ) {

        var rec = snap.val();
        if( !angular.isObject(rec) ) {
          rec = { $value: rec };
        }
        rec.$id = snap.name();
        rec.$priority = snap.getPriority();
        $firebaseUtils.applyDefaults(rec, this.$$defaults);

        //This is the line that I added to what I copied from the source
        angular.extend(rec, printMessageObj);


        this._process('child_added', rec, prevChild);
      }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this explanation, it could help me. what's printMessageObj in this example? there's no declaration to be found here, just the printMessageObjConstructor. thanks!

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-creating-angularfire-services