# firebaseArray limit one result by id

Tags: angularjs, firebase, chat

Please help me, I am developing a message system in my app to allow a courier to exchange messages with the customer.

There is a view showing a message list from all couriers the customer was in contact for each errand. And using firebaseArray return all the messages from each courier. And that's why I'm stuck cos I want to display only one message (the latest) per courier.  So if a customer  exchanging messages with Courier1, Courier2, Courier3, instead of showing all their messages in the list like this:

```
courier2 - message 6
courier3 - message 5
courier2 - message 4
courier1 - message 3
courier1 - message 2
courier1 - message 1
```

I only need to show in the list the latest message from each courier like this.

```
courier2 - message 6
courier3 - message 5
courier1 - message 3
```

Here is a sample of the messages tree in firebase :

```
"messages" : {
    "-K9cxQITQ0jE6I7aXMm_" : {
      "date_send" : 1454533620992,
      "dest" : "Alexandre",
      "dest_uid" : "c6f1c2ca-gg454-47ca-882c-ffb45c992d86",
      "picture_runner" : "img/hipster_male.png",
      "courier" : "Ludovic",
      "txt" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
    },
    "-K9dNYddxIbWXeasvYEK" : {
      "date_send" : 1454540733073,
      "dest" : "Alexandre",
      "dest_uid" : "c6f1c2ca-gg454-47ca-882c-ffb45c992d86",
      "picture_runner" : "img/hipster_female.png",
      "courier" : "Ophélia",
      "txt" : "Hello"
    },
    "-K9dO14ASsfXn4XrTJdX" : {
      "date_send" : 1454540857713,
      "dest" : "Alexandre",
      "dest_uid" : "c6f1c2ca-gg454-47ca-882c-ffb45c992d86",
      "picture_runner" : "img/hipster_female.png",
      "courier" : "Ophélia",
      "txt" : "Hello"
    }
```

And here is how I get the messages :

```
var fbAuth = fbaseUrl.getAuth();
        var query = fbaseUrl.child("messages").orderByChild("dest_uid").startAt(fbAuth.uid);
        $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that in NoSQL you often have to add some data to the model to allow for the use-case you want to implement.

In this case, since you want to show the latest message for each courier that the customer interacted with, you should store that information:

```
latest_message_per_courier_per_customer
    "Alexandre"
        "Ludovic": "-K9cxQITQ0jE6I7aXMm_"
        "Ophélia": "-K9dO14ASsfXn4XrTJdX"
    "Savad"
        "Ophélia": "other_message_id"
```

Now you can bind a `$firebaseArray` to the message list for the customer. You can either store the actual message in this structure. Or you can just store the ID of each message and then "join" the actual content by extending the [`$firebaseArray`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray). See for example: [How to extend returned objects in the list returned by $asArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836001/how-to-extend-returned-objects-in-the-list-returned-by-asarray)